# Database mapping methods

Tags: database

In another post, I came across some interesting methods to design the database schema. The methods were:

- Boolean Method
- Multiple Column Method
- Bridge Table Method

Can anybody post a link or describe briefly about the above mentioned techniques, because I tried searching them on Google and found nothing.

For a reference the post that I came across is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5495423/handling-a-many-to-many-dimension-when-all-dimensional-values-have-100-importanc)

Comment: Isn't anybody interested in answering this? :( I hope, I am not wrong in my explanations to what I am referring here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original post is talking about modelling a 1-to-many relationship, where a record belongs to many groups.

There's not a lot of detail in that post so I'm making inferences in giving definitions:

**Boolean method**
Probably using a [bitmask](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_%28computing%29) field to store membership of groups. Each group would correspond to a bit value. Requires a grasp of boolean logic to be able to query effectively.

**Multiple column method**
Extending the record to add one column per group to indicate membership. This is essentially a more human-readable implementation of the boolean method, but is painful to maintain when more groups are added.

**Bridge table method**
This one goes by several names (Wikipedia has it under the entry for [junction table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table)) - a new table is created, defining the link between the primary keys of the two source tables. This is the most robust solution.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've used all of these methods somewhere, but didn't know exactly of what are the specific names of these methods are. I thought initially that the bridge table method is referring to gerrand table or as you said junction table method, but wanted to clarify. Thanks again.